# 18.04 Samba errors, Windows Network & Meld

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, meld

I need help resolving a Samba “Windows Network Failure” problem and a [Meld](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/meld.1.html) file/folder compare delete problem.

```
1. What is causing the errors?
2. If permissions, what and where do I change them?
3. If samba, which package(s) do I need to install?
```

I recently upgraded two systems from Linux Mint 17.3 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using a clean install.  Since the upgrade, I have notice 2 problems with Ubuntu.  These problems did not exist with the older Mint installation, and I think the 2 problem are somewhat related: possibly due to permissions and/or Samba.

**Key systems information:**

```
• Lenovo M83 desktop, dual boot with Window 7
• Lenovo T510 laptop, dual boot with Windows 7
• Netgear ReadyNAS 104
• Ethernet wired network
```

**Windows Network Failure**

When I open the “File Manager” and click on “Other Locations”, I see the sd(x) devices on my computer, and the “Networks” area with the “Windows Network” icon.  I get the following error message when I click on the “Windows Network” icon.

“Unable to access location
Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory”

**Meld**

I have used “Meld” for several years to compare files and folders on the Mint installation.  I installed Meld using the Synaptic Package Manager on both systems.  The folders that I want to compare are on the ReadyNAS storage device on the Ethernet network.

I connect to the NAS on the network from File Manager and login to the primary share folder that I am working with.

I open Meld and select the “Directory Compare” option and then locate the source an target directories on the NAS.  In a simple test case, the compare screen says that both folders and file are the same with file permissions (rwx---).

I want to delete the folder on the left side (highlighted in red).  Clicking on the “Delete” icon on the toolbar, generates the following error message.

"Error deleting /run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-shares:server=.local,share=Dell_510/510_Backup/MyData_02_140504.../My_Data2_Joe/Zillow"
(some personal identifying text omitted above)

“g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported by backend (15)”.

I was not able to find a good solution to that error message on a Google search or askubuntu search.  The searches seems to point to a Samba issue, but I found the information inconclusive.  Hence, my request for help.  I could not post images since this is my first posting.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You've lost me with "upgraded two systems from Linux Mint 17.3 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using a clean install". Upgrade and clean install are obviously not the same, so what is that?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing wording.  I did a clean install using the Ubuntu CD.

Comment: Similar problem with a mounted android phone (via USB). Cannot delete files in phone internal memory from Meld (g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported by backend (15)) while I can delete them fine with Nautilus (after confirming for "permanent deletion", i.e., no undo/trash)

Comment: In my case it is probably related to the phone being mounted through USB as mtp. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193132/unable-to-perform-file-operations-on-a-mtp-device-mounted-via-gvfs-operation-n